# Memorize the last "correct" value of a sequence (for removing outliers)

Tags: r, function, outliers

I have a little problem in a function.
The aim of it is to remove outliers I've detected in my data.frame. They are detected when there's a too big difference with the previous correct value (e.g `c(1,2,3,20,30,4,5,6)`: "20" and "30" are the outliers). But my data is much more complex than this.

My idea is to consider the first two numeric values of my column as "correct". Then, I want to test each next value:

- if the difference between the tested value and the previous one is <20, then it's a new correct one, and the test must start again from this new correct value (and not from the previous correct one)
- if the same difference is >20, then it's a wrong one. An index must be put next to the wrong value, and the test must still continue from this same correct value, until a new correct value is detected

Here's an example with my function and a fake DF:

```
myts <- data.frame(x=c(12,12,35,39,46,45,33,5,26,28,29,34,15,15),z=NA) 

test <- function(x){
st1 = NULL
temp <- st1[1] <- x[1]
st1 <- numeric(length(x))
for (i in 2:(length(x))){ 
    if((!is.na(x[i])) & (!is.na(x[i-1]))& (abs((x[i])-(temp)) > 20)){
st1[i] <- 1
} } 
return(st1)
}

myts[,2] <- apply(as.data.frame(myts[,1]),2,test)  
myts[,2] <- as.numeric(myts[,2])
```

It does nearly the job, but the problem is that the last correct value is not memorized. It still does the test from the first correct value.
Due to this, rows 9 to 11 in my example are not detected. I let you imagine the problem on a 500,000 rows data.frame.

How can I solve this little problem? The rest of the function may be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update `temp` for any indices that aren't outliers:

```
test <- function(x) {
  temp <- x[1]
  st1 <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in 2:(length(x))){ 
    if(!is.na(x[i]) & !is.na(x[i-1]) & abs(x[i]-temp) > 20) {
      st1[i] <- 1
    } else {
      temp <- x[i]
    }
  } 
  return(st1)
}

myts[,2] <- apply(as.data.frame(myts[,1]),2,test)  
myts[,2] <- as.numeric(myts[,2])
myts
#     x z
# 1  12 0
# 2  12 0
# 3  35 1
# 4  39 1
# 5  46 1
# 6  45 1
# 7  33 1
# 8   5 0
# 9  26 1
# 10 28 1
# 11 29 1
# 12 34 1
# 13 15 0
# 14 15 0
```

One thing to note is that for loops in R will be quite slow compared to vectorized functions. However, because each element in your vector depends on a complicated way on the previous ones, it's tough to use R's built-in vectorized functions to efficiently compute your vector. You can convert this code nearly verbatim to C++ and use the Rcpp package to regain the efficiency:

```
library(Rcpp)
test2 <- cppFunction(
"IntegerVector test2(NumericVector x) {
  const int n = x.length();
  IntegerVector st1(n, 0);
  double temp = x[0];
  for (int i=1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (!R_IsNA(x[i]) && !R_IsNA(x[i]) && fabs(x[i] - temp) > 20.0) {
      st1[i] = 1;
    } else {
      temp = x[i];
    }
  }
  return st1;
}")
all.equal(test(myts[,1]), test2(myts[,1]))
# [1] TRUE

# Benchmark on large vector with some NA values:
set.seed(144)
large.vec <- c(0, sample(c(1:50, NA), 1000000, replace=T))
all.equal(test(large.vec), test2(large.vec))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(test(large.vec), test2(large.vec))
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr         min          lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#   test(large.vec) 2343.684164 2468.873079 2667.67970 2604.22954 2747.23919 3753.54901   100
#  test2(large.vec)    9.596752    9.864069   10.97127   10.23011   11.68708   16.67855   100
```

The Rcpp code is about 250x faster on a vector of length 1 million. Depending on your use case this speedup may or may not be important.

Comment: In my case, my function will be enough. It takes about 2 seconds for computing my whole vector. But I will get inspired with it for other loops in my code, which are much more slower than this function. Thanks again josilber!